# MongoDB Pricing

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services

I can't find a good article with MongoDB pricings and I am trying to estimate how much it would cost for my company if we would use it in production environment.

Could you help me to estimate/provide MongoDB pricing links to understand approximetly how much it would cost? And should it be cheaper compared to SQL Server Enterprise edition?

1. MongoDB with AWS hosting - I found the pricing for it but if I use an AWS instance with MongoDB, should I pay for the license as well or just for the instance?
2. MongoDB License - I read that there is an Enterprise edition but couldn't understand what are the differences between the enterprise and not enterprise and what are the costs differences.

I should have:

- 2 MongoDB Licenses.
- MongoDB should be high-available (in SQL Server for example I had to purchase the enterprise edition in order to make it highly-avaialable, should I do it with MongoDB as well?).
- Each instance will use 500GB Volume space.
- Platform - Windows Or Linux (still thinking).

I asked many questions but even if you provide me some answers it would be greatly appreciated. If I need to add some more data, let me know and I will add.

Answer (score 4):

You can use MongoDB Community Server, instead of MongoDB Enterprise Server, it does not have Licenses cost. This https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=nav#enterprise shows the extras that you get with Enterprise server.

MongoDB can be configured with replica-set config, which provides high-availability. This feature is part of both community & enterprise server, no need to pay anything extra for it.

If you host community server on AWS EC2, you would need to pay for EC2 instance (+ EBS volume) costs, no mongodb licenses cost.

For approximate idea on pricing you can also see: https://mlab.com/plans/pricing/ (they provide managed Database-as-a-Service for MongoDB on AWS).

Comment: It is worth noting that the licencing changed for use cases where there is a public facing web service.  This article has a bit of discussion about the change and its ramifications, https://www.geekwire.com/2019/mongodbs-licensing-changes-led-red-hat-drop-database-latest-version-server-os/.

Comment: Free, sort of. Just keep in mind that if you use MongoDB Community Server in public Internet, you are mandated by the license to publish all YOUR source code built on top of it under same SSPL license as well.